# WPF Binding, Not Updating Source, View Model has Base Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm stuck on this because it was working when the app was first created, and then another project was added and it was all built upon, now the feature has stopped working. Essentially, the system was able to toggle between having the navigation bar on the top, or the side. The properties are being updated in the view model, but the window is no longer updating the binding. We can focus on just one property to keep this thread smaller (since there are about 12 properties):

**Property Changed Class**

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the PropertyChange event for the property specified
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name to update. Is case-sensitive.</param>
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
}
```

**Page Base View Model**

```
public class PageBaseViewModel : ObservableObject, IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation - Adjust Row Span (Top: 1, Side: 2)
    /// </summary>
    private int _navigationRowSpan = 1;
    public int NavigatorRowSpan
    {
        get { return _navigationRowSpan; }
        set
        {
            if (_navigationRowSpan == value) return;

            _navigationRowSpan = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NavigatorRowSpan));
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Window View Model**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : PageBaseViewModel
{
}
```

**Main Window View**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Style="{DynamicResource myWindowStyle}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1080" Width="1920" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="115*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="827*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1743*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Path=NavigatorRowSpan}">
        
    </StackPanel>
    
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hopefully, it is something easy but here is what I have tried:

- Tried setting Path=Property
- Tried setting Mode=OneWay, Mode=TwoWay
- Tried setting ElementName=Property
- Tried setting just the property name in Binding {Binding Property}

I have been through all the posts on Stack Overflow I could find, and unable to find anything that has resolved this issue. This is why I am posting a new thread.

Update: This is the method that I use to change the property value

```
 public void ToggleNavigator()
    {
        if (IsTopNav)
        {
            NavigatorRowSpan = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            NavigatorRowSpan = 2;
        }
    }
```

This method does change the properties properly.

Comment: In such cases, I always use [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) to verify that the DataContext (and its values) is really what I expect, and in addition to check for binding errors.

Comment: @KlausGütter I'll check that out, but I have been running out of the debugger and the values in the datacontext are what I want them to be, but even though I am updating the property the view doesn't reflect the changes.

Comment: Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application? How do you set the NavigatorRowSpan property?

Comment: @Clemens No, there are no errors or warning in my project when debugging. When I click a checkbox it calls a method that switches all the values of my properties, which calls the set methods, which calls the update property event. I will update to include the method.

Comment: Are you sure you call the ToggleNavigator method on the same MainWindowViewModel instance that is used as the DataContext of the Window? How does that look exactly?

Comment: @Clemens Hm... I think that may be the issue.. My settings class (the page I update the navigator on) also inherits from the MainWindowViewModel, which has its own instance of these. Let me rework this page and see if I can fix it that. Thanks!!

Comment: @Clemens If I have multiple pages that have their own view model, but I want to have a set of shared objects in that view model across the board. What is the best way to implement that?

Comment: A common main view model that exposes child (i.e. page) view models as properties.

Comment: @Clemens I think I understand, you can answer the question with the issue and I'll mark it as best :) Thanks I have been starring at this issue for far too long to not think about multiple instances.